# How do I get tkinter to display these unicode characters?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, unicode, tkinter

I'm trying to get this to display correctly

> unicode: .

Well, This character range. It's the '[Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols Unicode block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols/utf8test.htm)'.
The thing about these character, they use two escapes for one letter so it's a little weird

> .  = \uD835\uDC12\uD835\uDC13\uD835\uDC00\uD835\uDC02\uD835\uDC0A\uD835\uDC0E\uD835\uDC15\uD835\uDC04\uD835\uDC11\uD835\uDC05\uD835\uDC0B\uD835\uDC0E\uD835\uDC16.\uD835\uDC02\uD835\uDC0E\uD835\uDC0C

Anyway, They actually output into my program correctly but they don't display.
From googling, I see that there are some problems with tkinter and unicode support.
[Picture related.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0aMa.png)

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be out of luck.  Those Unicode codepoints are UTF-16 surrogates.  When I used the correct Unicode codepoints for your string with `tkinter`, the error became:

```
_tkinter.TclError: character U+1d412 is above the range (U+0000-U+FFFF) allowed by Tcl
```

The string I used:

```
s = '\U0001d412\U0001d413\U0001d400\U0001d402\U0001d40a\U0001d40e\U0001d415\U0001d404\U0001d411\U0001d405\U0001d40b\U0001d40e\U0001d416.\U0001d402\U0001d40e\U0001d40c'

import unicodedata as ud
for c in s:
    print(ud.name(c))
```

Output:

```
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL S
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL T
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL A
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL C
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL K
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL O
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL V
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL E
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL R
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL F
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL L
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL O
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL W
FULL STOP
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL C
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL O
MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL M
```

I used the "hello world" sample from the Python 3.5 documentation:

```
import tkinter as tk

s = '\U0001d412\U0001d413\U0001d400\U0001d402\U0001d40a\U0001d40e\U0001d415\U0001d404\U0001d411\U0001d405\U0001d40b\U0001d40e\U0001d416.\U0001d402\U0001d40e\U0001d40c'

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = s
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                                            command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: In short: Tcl does not seem to support characters outside BMP. This means e.g. no emoji either.

Comment: It seems like Tk has the pieces in place to use UTF-16 on Windows. It uses UTF-8 internally, and to draw text it converts to a wide-character string and calls [`TextOutW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145133) (set in [`AllocFontFamily`](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/b8b14e85a2fe1c8901422b0d99cf64d2e94c92eb?txt=1&ln=1544) and called in [`MultiFontTextOut`](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/artifact/4830b197f8dd221678e14ecf4a87e80a1f1594be?txt=1&ln=1415)). Maybe the developers are just ironing out some kinks before officially incrementing `TCL_UTF_MAX` to 4.